# How can i pass the future Time to Wake up the Pending Intent?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I'm newer to android and i need to setup the event notification via broadcast receiver .

For now i'm passing the hard coded Time to get the Notification it's working properly... How can i pass the some future time to get the notification at that time...

Tried Code:

```
   EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
       int time = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
       PendingIntent pend_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                   this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
//calls the alarm
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(
                               ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
          + (time * 10000), pend_intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Calendar.getInstance()`  to set future time for AlarmManager. for example:

Prepare a `Calendar` instance with future time when you want to set Aalarm:

```
public  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month) - 1);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
```

Now pass `cal.getTimeInMillis()` as second parameter instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()+ (time * 10000)` in `alarmManager.set`

Answer (score 1):

Use Calancer to get time in millis.

For e.g.

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
mCalendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Now into you Alarm manager set method, Use Set Method like this.

```
mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, mCalendar.getTimeInMillis()
            + mTime * 10000, mPendingIntent);
```

Hope It Helps
Cheers
-Aman